# Div align not start from the top of contents

Tags: html, css

class `<div class="f-one">` and `<div class="f-two">` not start from the top of contents.

i want **Categories** , **Information** and **Contact Us** show in the same line.

Please have a look and help. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smithfoto/3yzo7575/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes in css. If you give  `display: inline-block;` then Just add `vertical-align:top;`

```
.f-one {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Updated your code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/3yzo7575/2/

Answer (score 0):

use this css for your `.f-one` and `.f-two`

```
.f-one {
    float:left;
    width: 220px;
}

.f-two {
    float:left;
    width: 460px;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3yzo7575/1/)

Comment: hi @catzilla if i use `float` it will be effect on `.footer{text-align: justify;}` 
http://jsfiddle.net/smithfoto/3yzo7575/3/

Comment: then your `.footer` should be `float: left` too... and width should be set appropriately.